# What is "."Operator in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL,'Root',IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P=B.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf'))
FROM BST AS B
ORDER BY N;
```

In this query what does `.` Operator in `B.N`?

Comment: A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name.

Comment: In this case, the dot allows selecting a property from the table referenced.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an operator, it's the delimiter between database, table, and column names or aliases. So `B.N` means column `N` in table `B`, where `B` is the alias for `BST` in the main query.

This is needed so you can distinguish between the `BST` table in the subquery and `BST` in the main query.

Comment: Yep, it's usually called a "namespace delimiter" or "namespace separator". It has a similar purpose as the slash "/" in linux paths or backslash "\" in Windows paths.

Comment: It's a plain English word, it's something that separates two things, just like a space is the separator between words.

Answer (score 1):

B is the alias of a table, N is a column of B